# How to add two different objects into a single object

Tags: java, object, arraylist, jaxb

Here is my function which is adding two different objects.

```
@GET
@Path("/getApplicationEnv")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public List<Object> getApplicationEnv(){

    List<ApplicationDTO> allApplication = applicationService.getAllApplication();                       
    List<Application> Applist = new ArrayList<Application>();

    for(ApplicationDTO d: allApplication)
    {
        Application a = new Application();

        a.setApplicationId(d.getApplicationId());
        a.setApplicationName(d.getApplicationName());
        a.setCreateTime(d.getCreateTime());
        a.setOwner(d.getOwner());   
        Applist.add(a);
    }   

    List<EnvironmentDTO> allEnvironments = environmentService.getAllEnvironments();

    List<Environment> Envlist = new ArrayList<Environment>();

    for(EnvironmentDTO d: allEnvironments)
    {
        Environment e = new Environment();

        e.setEnvironmentId(d.getEnvironmentId());
        e.setEnvironmentName(d.getEnvironmentName());
        e.setOwner(d.getOwner());
        e.setCreateTime(d.getCreateTime());
        Envlist.add(e);
    }

    ArrayList<Object> obj= new ArrayList<Object>();
    obj.addAll(Applist);
    obj.addAll(Envlist);

    return obj;
}
```

Currently I am using ArrayList of Object for adding two objects, but I am getting following error:

**SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
**

I have tried making a common parent class but I am having some attributes of both the class common so it is not possible to have a common parent class.

Can anyone please suggest me a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try changing

```
    ArrayList<Object> obj= new ArrayList<Object>();
    obj.addAll(Applist);
    obj.addAll(Envlist);
```

to

```
ArrayList<MyModel> obj= new ArrayList<MyModel>();
MyModel mm = new MyModel();
mm.setVal1(Applist);
mm.setVal2(Envlist);
obj.add(mm);
```

**UPDATE**

```
class MyModel
{
   private ApplicationDTO appDTO;
   private EnvironmentDTO enDTO;

   //getters settters here
}
```

here `MyModel` is just a model class with two `fields` as per your requirement..
hope this helps

Comment: Which two fields are you talking about in MyModel class ?

Comment: field to store your Applist and Envlist

Comment: Those fields are already in my ApplicationDTO and EnvironmentDTO class .I am adding my classes, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that object is not considered as an xml element. You can create an object like this

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyObject{
private List<Application> somename;
private List<Environment> somename2;
//Getters
//setters
}
```

and do like this

```
    public List<MyObject> getApplicationEnv(){
/*Some code*/
}
```

Comment: I am having all my getters and setters in ApplicationDTO and EnvironmentDTO. What getters and setters I will put in MyObject ?

Comment: For the lists private List<Application> somename;private List<Environment> somename2;